# Visual Studio Code, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

tensorflow **IS WORKING** in jupyter notebook, virtual environment, everywhere **EXCEPT** my Visual Studio Code. I have tried many methods, from re-installing, to pip install, to doing it in different virtual environment but still to no avail. I am using Windows 10, can anyone help me?

Comment: did you set the default python interpreter?

Comment: @PaulH Yes, I tried all the python interpreter

Comment: Can this command `python3 -m pip install tensorflow` work?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I tried, it does not work.

Comment: @userLS If you use the cmd window that comes with Windows to run python files, will he report an error?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT If I run through cmd, it will report the error as the title of this post, unless I run it through the conda virtual environment that I created.

Comment: I think the most likely reason is that this package is installed in a virtual environment which you can run correctly rather than a global environment. Can you solve the problem by using command `conda install package` in different virtual environments?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I can run those perfectly on Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda), but just not on Visual Studio Code

Comment: Because the problem is somewhat vague, I think it would be a good way to try to downgrade the jupyter extension or ask the developers in github